# Rails: How to make select list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, user-interface, web

I would like multiple line select with scrollbar in Ruby on Rails like in this img:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkq0u.jpg

```
  <select size="3">
    <option value="sy">sy</option>
    <option value="malakal">malakal</option>
    <option value="pigs go moo">pigs go moo</option>
  </select>
```

However I am unable find option for do this & only achieve dropdown
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jcdP.jpg

```
 <%= form.collection_select(:player_id, Player.all, :id, :name) %>
```

How do I make the dropdown into a list like in 1st image?

Comment: add option `multiple: true` with select

Comment: Hi! Ty mr. Deepak. Is now working ty!